# How to set margin-right to the end of the text

Tags: css

How would I set the right margin automatically to the end of the "contact" tab and not at the end of the page?

[image: html file]

```
nav{
    position: relative;
    margin-right: auto;
    width: auto;
    height: 50px;
    background: #f563ff;
    border-radius: 8px;
    font-size: 0;
    box-shadow: 0 2px 3px 0 rgba(0,0,0,.1);
```

Comment: Add  display: table-cell !important; to your nav class.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to set a margin rigth only to "contact" select its class and aplly it. If it doesn't have class so use nt

```css
ul{
    background-color: aquamarine;
    text-align: end;
}

li{
    display: inline;
}

li:nth-child(4){
    margin-right: 50px;
    background-color:bisque
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./index.css">
</head>
<body>
    <ul>
        <li>1</li>
        <li>2</li>
        <li>3</li>
        <li>contact</li>
    </ul>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

**You can use last-child properties and work well for the last menu**

***ul li:last:child{padding-right:30px;}***

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Project</title>
    <style>
          ul.main-menu li:last-child{padding-right:30px !important; }
    </style>
    
</head>
<body>
   <nav>
    <ul class="main-menu">
        <li>Home</li>
        <li>About</li>
        <li>Blog</li>
        <li>contact</li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</body>
</html>
```